# Undefined index error message in CRUD page : PHP AJAX JQUERY

Tags: php, crud

while using CRUD to one of my database driven website ..when we try to create / updating  database using Create or Update option i am getting following error

Notice: Undefined index: crud_table in /home/sulabgqh/public_html/leads/controllers/grid_controller.php on line 89

i wnat to know what is the possible error   , for reference below is the public declation of variable 'crud_table' table name

```
/********************* PUBLIC METHODS ********************/ 

public function setDbTable($table){
    $_SESSION['crud_table'] = $table;
}


public function setPrimaryKey($primaryId) {
    $_SESSION['crud_primary_key']=$primaryId;
}
```

and contructor is used here  ..

```
 /********************* CONSTRUCTOR ********************/
    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['crud_table'] = null;
        $_SESSION['crud_title_map'] = null;
        $_SESSION['crud_actions'] = null;
        $_SESSION['crud_primary_key']='id';
        $_SESSION['crud_per_page']=10;
    }
```

and Crete  function goes like this

```
public function create(){
        //setting from grid object
        $table  = $_SESSION['crud_table']; 
        $pk = $_SESSION['crud_primary_key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Session-Variable isnt set, because of that it is "undefined". Try to check the varibale before u use it in the function like

```
if(isset($_SESSION['crud_table'])){
do stuff...
}
```

Is the Session startet correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put session_start() at the top of all scripts that are using sessions, this is the most common reason for session variables not being set.

session_start() doesn't just start a session, it checks if one is already running, if so it loads that one if not it creates a new one.

Comment: as you can see in my constructor i called session_start().

Comment: Check the session is starting correctly it returns FALSE on failure, if using cookie based sessions it must be called before any output is sent to the browser. Also why is the table name being stored in the session and not in a member variable of the class?